# Laravel 5 and Carbon discrepancy on Forge

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

Hopefully I'm not mad and I'm only missing something. I have a project on Laravel 5.0 and I have a requestExpired function called every time I have an incoming request. Now, to calculate the difference between current time on the server and the timestamp within the request I'm using:

```
$now = Carbon::now('UTC');
$postedTime = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp, 'UTC');
```

For some reason request is always rejected because it's expired. When I debug these two lines from above and just dump data, I get:

> REQUEST'S TIMESTAMP IS: 1423830908279
>
> $NOW OBJECT: Carbon\Carbon Object
>   (
>       [date] => 2015-02-13 12:35:08.000000
>       [timezone_type] => 3
>       [timezone] => UTC
>   )
>
> $POSTEDTIME OBJECT: Carbon\Carbon Object
>   (
>       [date] => 47089-05-28 09:37:59.000000
>       [timezone_type] => 3
>       [timezone] => UTC
>   )

Any ideas why $postedTime is so wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: for some strange reason webhook calls from remote API have 13 digits long timestamps and that's why my dates were so wrong.